# Копирование из таблицы в таблицу с условием MySql

Tags: mysql

Такая задача: есть переменная(например i), исходя из её значения  данные из одной таблицы копируются в другую. То есть если i = 1, то данные из таблицы "lesson" будут копироваться в DEP_1.lesson, если i = 2, то в DEP_2.lesson и тд.
Изначально хотела сделать через операторы условий (CASE, IF), но выдает ошибку.
В итоге вариант вот такой:

```
DROP 
  DATABASE IF EXISTS lessons;
  CREATE DATABASE lessons;
  USE lessons;

SELECT @index_db = 1;

CREATE TABLE `list_lesson`(
  `id` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `topic` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, 
  `duration` DECIMAL(4, 2)NOT NULL, 
  `date` DATE NOT NULL, 
  `teacher` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
  `people_planned` SMALLINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO list_lesson (`topic`, `duration`, `date`, `teacher`, `people_planned`) VALUES ('lesson_1', 2.5, '2011-03-13' , 'Cat', 10);

DELETE FROM DEP_1.lesson WHERE `id` > 0;
INSERT INTO DEP_1.lesson SELECT * FROM list_lesson WHERE @index_db = 1;

DELETE FROM DEP_2.lesson WHERE `id` > 0;
INSERT INTO DEP_2.lesson SELECT * FROM list_lesson WHERE @index_db = 2;
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли более "красивый" вариант записи последних 4 срок, потому что таких условий мне нужно 15 штук, хотелось бы избежать огромного количества повторения строк.

P.S. Условие WHERE в последней и предпредпоследней строчке не работает.

Comment: Для решения подобной задачи нужен [динамический SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html). Однако наличие однотипных таблиц однозначно указывает на денормализованность данных, что является серьёзной архитектурной ошибкой.

Comment: Не очень понимаю, как поможет в этой ситуации динамический SQL, если можете привести пример использования, буду благодарна.

Comment: Если вдруг недостаточно примеров в документации - воспользуйтесь поиском по форуму, что ли... тут примеров - вагон.

Comment: Подскажите, тогда, пожалуйста, возможно ли сделать мою задачу через CASE или IF, используя динамический sql? То есть написать условие "если переменная равна 1, то одна таблица копируется в другую".

Comment: CASE/IF могут использоваться исключительно в статических объектах (хранимая процедура, определённая пользователем функция и пр.). Ну и список таблиц придётся хардкодить.